# Probability that n is achieved by multiplying two random integers from two given ranges

Tags: python, algorithm

So here is the challenge: I am given four numbers: `a,b,c,d`. Then the number `n` is given which describes how many numbers to check will be. Then these numbers are inputted and the goal is to find which probability that number will be gotten if multiply two random numbers one from the range `a to b` and one from `c to d` range. Finally, I need to output that probability in 'p/q' format. I figured out the solution and it works but the problem is when working with bigger numbers it uses too much time. I also have another solution where I first create a list with all possible combinations but in that case it uses too much memory.

```
from math import gcd

a,b,c,d = (map(int,input().split(" ")))
combs_quantity = (b-a+1)*(d-c+1)

def findProb(z):
    repeats = 0
    nec_mulps = [z//x for x in range(a,b+1) if z%x == 0]
    for n in nec_mulps:
        if n in range(c,d+1):
            repeats+=1
    probGCD = gcd(repeats,combs_quantity)
    return str(repeats//probGCD) + "/" + str(combs_quantity//probGCD)

probability = []
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    probability.append(findProb(int(input())))
for p in probability:
    print(p)
```

Comment: What are limits for a,b,c,d?

Comment: 1 <= a,b,c,d <= 10^9

Comment: This comment don't about the correct solution, but `if n in range(c,d+1)` is strange. I think it works O(n). Use `if c <= n <= d` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Get all divisors of `n`

For every divisor `Z` that belongs to range `a..b` check whether complementary divisor `n//Z` lies in range `c..d`

Comment: Your implementation has complexity (b-a+1)*(d-c+1), but this one - sqrt(n) (complexity of finding divisors)

Answer (score 0):

@MBo said above that complexity is `sqrt(z)`. You can to calculcate `repeats` as:

```py
    divisors = []
    i = 1
    while i * i <= z:
        if z % i == 0:
            divisors.append(i)
            if i * i < z:
                divisors.append(z // i)
        i += 1
    repeats = 0
    for divisor in divisors:
        if a <= divisor <= b and c <= z // divisor <= d:
            repeats += 1
```